ASP.NET Core Project Not Listing in Aspire Dashboard After Local Kubernetes Deployment
I have an ASP.NET Core project that contains two simple projects:
A Web API that returns weather data.
A Frontend that consumes this data from the API.
Everything works perfectly in the development environment. However, when I deploy the project locally on Kubernetes:
The Aspire dashboard does not list the projects.
There are no error logs or any indication of an issue.
The Web API and Frontend work independently when accessed directly, but they are not connected (the frontend is unable to consume the API data).
Steps I Followed:
Created Docker images for both the Web API and the Frontend.
Deployed both images to my local Kubernetes cluster.
Verified that both services are running and accessible individually.
Why are the projects not listed in the Aspire dashboard despite being deployed successfully?
